If statements to process a specific numeric value of a variable always fall into the last if statement no matter the value of the variable
I want to process different functions depending on the total RAM capacity of a PC.
To do this I came up with that function:
:function.texture_streaming
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (
    `PowerShell -Command "(Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure Capacity -Sum).Sum/1GB"`
) do (
    set "ram=%%a"
)
if "%ram%" lss "16" (
    call :error.insufficient_ram "!ram!"
    endlocal
    goto :prompt.performance
)
if "%ram%" geq "16" if "%ram%" lss "32" (
    call :subroutine.limited_texture_streaming
    endlocal
    goto :prompt.performance
)
if "%ram%" geq "32" (
    call :subroutine.full_texture_streaming
    endlocal
    goto :prompt.performance
    )
endlocal
goto :prompt.performance

My issue is that no matter the value of %ram% it's always the last if statement that gets processed. Even if I set the value of %ram% to 8 manually it still processes the last if statement when I it should process the first one. I have also redirected the value of %ram% to a text file to see if there are any spaces but there are none.

Please read my answer on Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files. The usage of " in an IF condition results always in a string comparison and not an integer comparison as wanted by you. Use if %ram% LSS 16 and if %ram% GEQ 16 if %ram% LSS 32 and if %ram% GEQ 32. There should be made sure with set "ram=" at top and with if not defined ram goto :EOF after the FOR /F loop that this environment variable could be successfully defined with a 32-bit signed integer value at all.

Some more suggestions: Replace the entire for /f command block by the single command line for /F %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure Capacity -Sum).Sum/1GB"') do set "ram=%%I". Delayed variable expansion is not needed at all. Replace setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion by setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion or remove that line and all endlocal and of course replace call :error.insufficient_ram "!ram!" by call :error.insufficient_ram "%ram%".

I would advise that you change your command to use the CIM cmdlet rather than the WMI one. Here it is without shortening: For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-CimInstance Cim_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum).Sum / 1GB" 2^>NUL') Do Set "ram=%%G".

@Mofi I have read through the answer you mentioned and adjusted other parts of my script accordingly. I didn't know equ is different from ==. I have also unquoted the variable and integer value in each if statement, which made it work! @Compo I have changed to using CIM instead of WMI like you suggested. Thank you both for your suggestions and help.

Thanks to @Mofi and @Compo I was able to solve the issue.
This is the now working code:
setlocal
rem Initialize variable.
set "ram="

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (
    `PowerShell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-CIMInstance CIM_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum).Sum / 1GB"`
) do (
    set "ram=%%a"
)

if not defined ram (
    call :error.function_failed "determining your total RAM capacity"
    endlocal
    goto :prompt.performance
)

if %ram% lss 16 (
    pause
    call :error.insufficient_ram "%ram%"
    endlocal
    goto :prompt.performance
)

if %ram% geq 16 if %ram% lss 32 (
    call :subroutine.limited_texture_streaming
    endlocal
    goto :prompt.performance
)

if  %ram% geq 32 (
    call :subroutine.full_texture_streaming
    endlocal
    goto :prompt.performance
)

endlocal
goto :prompt.performance

